# Help submitting an asp.net form with jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm trying to post the entire asp.net form to a certain url.

I have tried:

```
$.post("http://www.someaddress.com", $("form").serialize());
```

I have also tried:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"http://www.someaddress.com",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(){
        alert('yay');
    }
});
```

In both cases the submit is fine but no data is passed along with it.

When i test the form.serialize() in firebug console, this shows my form serialized just fine. When i view the submit in fiddler, i can see that the data part is not set. Maybe im not understanding the data part, but every single tutorial shows this as the way to go -> serialize the form and set that as data. What must i do to get my serialized form as the data in my request?

What am i missing? Also - why does the NET tab in firebug show all these requests as method OPTIONS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this

```
url:"http://www.someaddress.com"
```

just an example or do you try to access a foreign domain? (which would explain the problem).

Based on your comment, the [ajax same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) does not allow to access a foreign domain.

Comment: im definitely trying to access a foreign domain - and yes its an example

Comment: ah ok - could you explain to me how/why this works when i put an asp button on my page and set a postbackurl to a foreign domain? i basicly want to achieve the same without the redirect..

Comment: basically, impossible. Do you have access to the `foreign domain` ? If so you may use `jsonp` to transfer data.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do a Ajax request to a foreign domain. As this is not allowed (against security) in javascript to access a foreign page ( not on your domain )